# Strange line space behavior with vspace

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I noticed an unexpected different line spacing of the titlepage what drives me crazy. The left page is the MWE, the right page without the `\\` in front of `Name`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\centering
\Huge
\textbf{UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUU}
\vspace{\baselineskip}\\
\textbf{UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUU}
{\rmfamily\Large
\vspace{5\baselineskip}\\Name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any idea what causes this? Thanks alot!

Cheers,
Stephan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `\vspace` in horizontal mode then it is added after the current line. which is almost never wanted, use `\\[12pt]` in preference.

If you use a font size command and close the group before ending the paragraph the line spacing restores at the group end so the paragraph uses large fonts on a normalsize baseline and inconsistent spacing. Always include a blank line or `\par` before the `}`